# Is it possible to prove that $M$ is an integer with $p+M \over x$ is always an integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, number-theory

Given a prime number $p$ and a set $S$ of $n$ **rational numbers**. Multiply all $n$ **rational numbers** we get a number $M$. For each number $x$ in the set $S$, we have $\frac{p+M}{x}$ is an **integer**. Is it possible to prove that $M$ is also an **integer**?

For $n = 2$, let $S=\left\{x,y\right\}$. Then $\frac{p+M}{x}=\frac{p}{x}+y$, $\frac{p+M}{y}=\frac{p}{y}+x$ are integers, then multiply the two numbers we have $\frac{p^2}{M}+2p + M$ is an integer, thus $\frac{p^2}{M} + M=\alpha$ is an integer. If $M=\frac{A}{B}$ with $A$, $B$ are coprime, then $B^2\times p^2+A^2=\alpha A B$ so $B|A^2$ then $B=1$, thus $M$ is an integer.

Is it true that for every $n>2$, $M$ is an integer? If not, then what are the conditions of $n$ so that $M$ must be an integer?

Edit: If $M$ is an integer, then is $M$ a power of $p$?

Comment: It seems that in your proof for $n = 2$ the fact that $p$ is prime does not play a role - $p$ being an integer is enough. Does primality of $p$ become important form $n = 3$ onwards, e.g. do you have a counterexample for $n \geq 3$ with composite integer $p$?

Comment: Your proof works for $n\geq 3$ as well and looks like $p$ can be any integer.

Comment: @Vincent I have edited my question. I think that $M$ should be the power of $p$, this is true with $p=2$?

Comment: @YongHaoNg I have edited my question. I think that $M$ should be the power of $p$, this is true with $p=2$?

Comment: @apple Looks like the answer solves this new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach can be generalized to give that

$$\frac{(p+M)^n}{M}\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Letting $M=a/b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b>0$,

$$\frac{(bp+a)^n}{ab^{n-1}}\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Since $b|(bp+a)^n$, we have $b|a^n$, which means $b=1$. Thus

$$\frac{(p+a)^n}{a}\in\mathbb{Z},$$

which implies $a|p^n$ and thus $a$ is a (positive or negative) power of $p$.

**Remark.** We did not use the primality of $p$ anywhere in the proof that $b=1$, only in the proof that $a$ is a power of $p$.